# How to handle Transport error in elastic search python client?

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch

I am uploading pandas dataframe to elastic (using elasticsearch==6.3.1), if the dataframe size is less 100MB it works fine, i am using a solution from [How to export pandas data to elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49726229/how-to-export-pandas-data-to-elasticsearch)

```
def rec_to_actions(df):
    for record in df.to_dict(orient="records"):
        yield ('{ "index" : { "_index" : "%s", "_type" : "%s" }}'% (INDEX, TYPE))
        yield (json.dumps(record, default=int))
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
e = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
r = e.bulk(rec_to_actions(df))
```

This works perfect, but for dataframe over 100MB it throws Transport Error

```
raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
TransportError: TransportError(413, '')
```

How to handle this?
i tried setting http.max_content_length: 350mb in elasticsearch.yml file, but still getting error.

Also one more question is how to add a timestamp field along with the above function?

Comment: You should definitely send your data frame in several batches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send them in batches or use Parallel bulk, example:

```
from elasticsearch import helpers
results = list(helpers.parallel_bulk(e, generator_fn() , thread_count=2, chunk_size=400, request_timeout=1000, raise_on_error=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to chunk the dataframe, essentially uploading to elastic search in smaller batches.

```
import json
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

def rec_to_actions(df, index):
    for record in df.to_dict(orient="records"):
        yield '{ "index" : { "_index" : "%s", "_type": "_doc"}}' % index
        yield json.dumps(record, default=int)

def push_to_elasticsearch(df,
                          index,
                          es_params):
    es = Elasticsearch(
        hosts=[dict(
            host=es_params['host'],
            port=es_params['port'],
            scheme='https'
        )],
        http_auth=(es_params['username'], es_params['password'])
    )
    r = es.bulk(rec_to_actions(df=df,
                               index=index))

    print(f'--> {index} Data upload complete :: ElasticSearch')
    return r

def split_dataframe(df, chunk_size = 10000):
    chunks = list()
    num_chunks = len(df) // chunk_size + 1
    for i in range(num_chunks):
        chunks.append(df[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size])
    return chunks

chunked_df = split_dataframe(df = your_dataframe)
for chunk in chunked_df:
    push_to_elasticsearch(df = chunk,
                          index = es_index,
                          es_params = elastic_search_params)
```